# Android Face Detection using HaarClassifiers and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, haar-classifier

I'm doing a face detection application on Android using `Haar Classifiers`.

I'm working with an `AsyncTask` and I have a problem.

After doing the face detection I want to update the `UI` in the `onProgressUpdate()` method and draw a rectangle on each discovered face.

The detection works at 14 fps, but the rectangle gets drawn only by half, or less.

How can I draw the entire rectangle using this `AsyncTask`?

I have to skip frames or slow down the process?

Thanks